# is there any wordpress plugin to send email notification to commentators?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a plugin that will send an email to someone who comments on my blog when someone replies to their comment?

Thanks in advance for any info

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Subscribe to Double-Opt-In Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-double-opt-in-comments/) which I also use on my blog. If you don't want a "double-opt-in" (what you should really want to have) you can take the [Subscribe to Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/) plugin.

Managing the subscriptions for users and blog owners is quite easy with at least the first plugin (haven't tested the second as I need to have double-opt-in for my blog).